# Providing the WPF designer with an image at DesignTime

Tags: wpf

This is a restatement of my question, the revision history contains the original mess.

What it boils down to is "How do I get the application's directory from my WPF application, at design time?"

Which duplicates the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808856/how-do-i-get-the-applications-directory-from-my-wpf-application-at-design-time) so if you happen to be passing by please vote to close, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the application's directory from my WPF application, at design time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808856/how-do-i-get-the-applications-directory-from-my-wpf-application-at-design-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the image to be "Content - Copy if newer"? If you switch it to "Resource" you can use the following path to reference the file:

```
"/MyImage.JPG"
```

or a longer version

```
"pack://application:,,,/MyImage.JPG"
```

given that the image is in the root of the project, otherwise just change the URI to

```
"/Some/Path/MyImage.JPG"
```

### UPDATE 1:

For me, the longer pack uri syntax works with an image marked as "Content - Copy if newer" as well. However, the shorter syntax does not work. I.e:

This works:

```
"pack://application:,,,/MyImage.JPG"
```

This does *NOT* work:

```
"/MyImage.JPG"
```

I my example I added the image to the root of the project, and marked it as "Content". I then bound the design time data context to a view model with a property returning the longer pack URI above. Doing that results in the Content image being shown correctly at design time.

### UPDATE 2:

If you want to load a bitmap source from a pack uri, you can do so by using another overload of the `BitmapFrame.Create` which takes an URI as the first parameter.

If I understand your problem correctly you get the string with the pack uri as the first item in the object array that is passed to your converter. From this string you want to load a BitmapSource.

Since the string contains a pack URI, you can create an actual URI from the string and then use that URI to load the BitmapSource:

```
var imagePath = values[0] as string;
// ...
try
{
    var packUri = new Uri(imagePath);

        BitmapSource bitmap = BitmapFrame.Create(packUri, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Erik, see my edit, I've realised that the problem with pack://application:,,,/MyImage.JPG is not that I had tried the wrong uri but that I'm actual binding through an IValueConverter, could I resolve the pack uri in my converter somehow?

Comment: I've edited the answer. Take a look and check if I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I could do it that way, and perhaps I should be using URIs rather than paths, but I will have to think about if it agrees with my runtime requirements, for now the solution I have posted as an answer allows me to locate the exe directory and construct a design time path.  I will give your approach a try over the weekend, thanks for your help.

Comment: For me this did it : pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication2;component/Resources/Images/Samples/cat.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Just return the exact path of the image from your entity in *ImagePath* property, such as ..

"C:\MyImage.JPG"

..

OR

..

"C:\MyApp\bin\Debug\MyImage.JPG"

Then your binding (i.e. `<Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />`) in .xaml will start working..

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by leveraging the clevers found in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808856/how-do-i-get-the-applications-directory-from-my-wpf-application-at-design-time).

```
public class DMyViewModel : PhotoViewModelBase
{
    public override string ImagePath
    {
        get
        {
            string applicationDirectory =
                (from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                 where assembly.CodeBase.EndsWith(".exe")
                 select System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(assembly.CodeBase.Replace("file:///", ""))
                 ).FirstOrDefault();
            return applicationDirectory + "\\MyImage.JPG";
        }
    }
}
```