# How to read file from the installation folder of app using c#?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I am reading a file using File.ReadAllText("filename.txt"). This file is located in very same folder where the .exe file is located (c:/program files/installation folder). But windows app looks into System32 folder for this file by default.

**I don't want to hard code the path of the file.

Comment: How is this `exe` launched? Maybe there's something that modifies the current working directory?

Comment: Its a windows service...always running....just scheduled to invoke certain tasks based on specified time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this function:

```
using System.Reflection;

private string MyDirectory()
    {
        return Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    }
```

Then use

```
File.ReadAllText(MyDirectory() + @"\filename.txt");
```

Answer (score 9):

```
string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase );
```

Gives the directory of the exe.
So using that with Path.Combine will give the desired result:

```
string filenamelocation = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "filename.txt");
```

Answer (score 4):

A lot shorter

```
File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "filename.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

So you need directory of your application?
In that case, there are some good answers already on SO, for example:

[Getting the application's directory from a WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938421/getting-the-applications-directory-from-a-wpf-application)