# SQLite Can't find a table

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, mvvm

I have this code in App.xaml.cs:

```
    private SQLiteConnection dbCon;

    public void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("testdb.sqlite");

        dbCon = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=testdb.sqlite;Version=3;");
        dbCon.Open();

        string query = "create table if not exists Settings(Key nvarchar(max), Value nvarchar(max));";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(query, dbCon);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

This runs just fine... but then on ShellViewModel.cs I have this:

```
    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        dbCon = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=testdb.sqlite;Version=3;");
        dbCon.Open();

        string query = "Select Value from Settings where (Key = 'isFirstTime')";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(query, dbCon);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //if(no information or first time)
        //      show registerationview.xaml
        //else
        this.ActivateItem(new MainViewModel()); // show main view.
    }
```

The thing is I get "Table not found" in the above code.

The only reason for this I could think about is the fact that `App.xaml.cs` is in the root directory of the project, while `ShellViewModel.cs` is inside the `ViewModels` folder, but I have no idea how to make it point to that specific database file in the root directory, if that's even the problem.

What is the problem/solution?
I tried finding answers but all the questions were answered with 'possible causes to the problem', so they don't really help.

Answer (score 0):

use Full path in all locations where working with  SQLite database as below

```
string fullPath = Path.Combine(ApplicationDataBaseFolderPath, "testdb.sqlite");

SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(fullPath);
```

And

```
dbCon = new SQLiteConnection(String.Format("Data Source={0};Version=3;", fullPath));
```

You can use one of the answer for the [Getting the application's directory from a WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938421/getting-the-applications-directory-from-a-wpf-application) SO Question and find the aplication directory and then combine that with Folder Name where your database should locate.

```
string ApplicationDataBaseFolderPath = Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "AppData");
```

Comment: Thanks. what is `ApplicationDataBaseFolderPath` though? It's not recognized.