# Cannot get directories from source

Tags: c#, debugging, directoryinfo

I need your help to solve this small issue. I gave a source path such as `"\version\test"` in my c# project. But when I run it, i want to get folders from source but i got error because source path is incorrect due to `\bin\debug\version\test`. I only need to read folders from project's path not debug. How to solve this problem? Your advice much appreciated. thanks

Comment: the short answer is `"..\..\version\test"` but the correct answer may depend on what this is being used for as it may be unsafe to assume this directory will be there

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to read some files in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a relative path, and the working directory when you run your application is `\bin\debug`.
So you should either set the working directory to the project directory in the debug properties of the project, or use a different relative path, such as `..\..\version\test`

Answer (score 0):

If your application is winforms application then it is:
Application.StartupPath

If your application is WPF application then please see below link:
[Getting the application's directory from a WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938421/getting-the-applications-directory-from-a-wpf-application)

Comment: That would still return the debug folder

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get path use following code sample:

```
string path =new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName;
```

This will give you current solution folder path.