# how to get database path programmatically in wpf application

Tags: wpf

the wpf application save the sql compact database at a path like this:
C:\Users\NOURHAN\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Data\59KZ6KD9.COJ\VHH739C4.V9L\dr_h..tion_3ae2203d6bcb251a_0001.0000_e052c665d8e18ffa\Data\data

the path folder names changes from pc to another

at the connection string it connect to database properly using :
connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\db.sdf"

but I want to copy database file ,so I want to get the database path

I tried to use : System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);

but it isn't reach to the exact path

any help please?

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938421/getting-the-applications-directory-from-a-wpf-application?

Comment: yes,I tried it's get the exe app directory and it's different from the database directory

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using ClickOnce and I believe the method you are seeking is `ApplicationDeployment.DataDirectory` (see [this MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.datadirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).