# How to find root path of wpf app and create folder on root directory for saving images?

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: I have the app called osc and i want to create folder in root path and save image to that folder.]

I want to save images at folder like "osc/Screenshots/EmpName/EmpId/scr.jpg"

how to create folder and save image on this path

help me

thanks in advance

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938421/getting-the-applications-directory-from-a-wpf-application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to get application folder path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041332/best-way-to-get-application-folder-path)

Comment: i tried that but i getting exe path but i want root path of wpf app

Comment: Then specify your purpose. Do you want to store your files as ressources in the project or in the output directory?

Comment: In project root directory as shown in image my image path would be like  "osc/Screenshots/EmpName/EmpId/scr.jpg"

Comment: 1. Put the path in the config file 2. Use it in code 3. Profit

Comment: its true but if i want to use this app in other PCs also so i cant take it as a static

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the string representing the path:

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Probably you want to do something like the following:

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
```

To create a new path based on root folder:

```
var imagePath = path + @"\MyAppName\Images"

if (!Directory.Exists(imagePath)) 
{   
   DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(imagePath);
}
```

EDIT: As alternative you may use specials folders. For example LocalApplicationData, in this folder you can place machine scoped data of your application per user. Below the variable localData will be

> C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local

where USER_NAME is the user profile.

```
string localData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
var imagePath = localData + @"\Images";

if (!Directory.Exists(imagePath)) 
{   
    DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(imagePath);
}
```

Comment: it gives me the path of my exe like osc/bin/release/screenshots.... but i want to create folder in root directory osc/.

Comment: yes but it returns bin/release folder path                                                              i want root path of app

Comment: @SaurabhSolanki, when you launch your app from Visual Studio, the root is the Release or Debug folder. When you install your application, then the root folder will be the installation folder.

Comment: thank you.....@ E-Bat  Yes, it relolved my issue and it saves screenshots to the root directory of my project , but the problem is occured that after installing the application the app is installed in c:/programfiles(86)/projectfolder drive so my app can't access to that folder to write image files. due to C drive is unaccessible.

Comment: @SaurabhSolanki, you can use the specials folders available in windows. .NET provides a consistent way to access to those folders. For example ApplicationData. Have a look to my edit in the post.

Answer (score 2):

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` will give you the path to your application folder.

Comment: it gives me the path of my exe like osc/bin/release/screenshots....                 but i want to create folder in root directory osc/.