# Where is the 'Projects Location' setting in Visual Studio 2019 stored?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I would like to know where the 'Projects Location' setting in Visual Studio 2019 is stored so I can read into a C# WPF app.

The setting I mean can be found manually as follows from the Visual Studio main menu:

Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | Locations

It is the value in the 'Projects Location' text box that I am looking to get.

I don't know where this value would be stored to retrieve it.

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938421/getting-the-applications-directory-from-a-wpf-application

Comment: I really wonder why you would need this; but its stored in %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_<somenumber>\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings. Note that there might be several parallel installations of VS2019.