# How to play mp3 file from relative folder?

Tags: wpf

I tried to play a mp3 file from relative folder. I defined xaml look like.

```
<MediaElement x:Name="background_Sound" Source="\Music\Background_sound.mp3" LoadedBehavior="Pause" Volume="0.3" />
```

I want to play this file when the form open:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            background_Sound.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;

        }
```

But nothing happens.
I tried full path other mp3 Source = "E:\test.mp3", it worked well.

I tried to find more solutions from internet. Can you give me your advance.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the application's directory from a WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938421/getting-the-applications-directory-from-a-wpf-application)

Comment: Perhaps you need to remove \ at the beginning of path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that

- the MP3-File is located in a folder named `Music` in your Visual Studio Project
- its `Build Action` is set to `Content`
- the `Copy to Output Directory` option is set to `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`

Then load the file by a valid relative path URI, without a leading `\`.

```
<MediaElement Source="Music\Background_sound.mp3" .../>
```

Alternative URIs are `".\Music\Background_sound.mp3"` or `"Music/Background_sound.mp3"` or `"./Music/Background_sound.mp3"`